# Cannot Direct Update after fixpack WL 6.1.0.1

Tags: ibm-mobilefirst, worklight-studio, worklight-server, worklight-security

after the fixpack in subject, i cannot manage to direct update my application.

It notify me that there is a new version available, but when i hit Update it keeps saying that the download failed (both on iOS and Android).

I attached my android to adb and i noticed those lines in the console:

> Authentication error: Unable to respond to any of these challenges:
>   {wl-composite-challenge=WWW-Authenticate: WL-Composite-Challenge}
>
> java.io.IOException: Error downloading update file The following
>   message has been received from the server instead of the expected
>   application update zip file: HTTP/1.1 401 Unauthorized
>   /*-secure-{"challenges":{"wl_deviceNoProvisioningRealm":{"token":"1or0tj7gnoev1rn06s188j4u9h"},"wl_antiXSRFRealm":{"WL-Instance-Id":"np8c8o3c4dk1k7s79i2ikddfab"}}}*/
>
> at
>   com.worklight.androidgap.plugin.WebResourcesDownloaderPlugin$WebResourcesDownloader.downloadZipFile(WebResourcesDownloaderPlugin.java:364)

To complete the information I deployed the IBM_Worklight_Console with no security role in its web.xml and we have Worklight 6.1.0.1 installed on WAS Network Deployment 7.0.0.23 running AIX.

Before the fixpack, everything worked well.

Thank you

EDIT: here you can see my application-descriptor.xml and my server configuration:
[image]
[image]

Comment: Is your application protected by any security tests? If the user is not authenticated against the security test when attempting to download the direct update you will get a 401. Does this happen everytime or does it only happen in specific cases such as after the session ends

Comment: Did you upgrade both studio and server? Did you rebuild anything after upgrading? Any other changes?

Comment: @Axel92Dev, any news since May?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I forgot about this stack, however I found the problem.
When I open my application, the WL Framework asks for new available update. In the same time, my application ask an adapter for some data, before the WL server can response about the Update. So if it arrives first the response of my adpater, then the Update response will contain a different requestID causing a 403 forbidden.

I don't know if I explained it clearly, however the temporary fix is to put updateSilently: true, not disturbing the direct update.